# what is trying to be said by "races up and down the ballot"

Tags: meaning-in-context

in this headline:

"Where Abortion Is on the Ballot
The outcome of November’s elections will affect abortion access for million of Americans. Activists on both sides are focused on races up and down the ballot."

"races up and down the ballot" up and down the country?

Answer (score 2):

The **races** are the competitions where candidates try to get elected (see [*race, noun (2), definition 1b*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/race) here)

The **ballot** is the list of elected positions and the candidates who are competing.  A ballot usually has multiple positions on it: Senator, Representative, Judge, County Dogcatcher, etc.

[image]

So the **races up and down the ballot** means "the competitions, for the entire list of positions that we are voting on, from the least important to the most important."